# How do I add duplicate rows from one DataFrame to another based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

```
tbl_1:

+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | x |
| 3 | 4 | y |
| 5 | 6 | z |
+---+---+---+

tbl_2:

+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 3 | 4 | b |
| 5 | 6 | c |
+---+---+---+
```

How do I append the duplicate rows in `tbl_2` to `tbl_1` as follows:

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | x |
| 3 | 4 | y |
| 5 | 6 | z |
| 3 | 4 | b |
| 5 | 6 | c |
+---+---+---+
```

I've tried using `duplicated()` but I can't figure out how to go from comparing within one DataFrame to comparing between DataFrames...

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pd.concat` of `tbl_1` and after selecting the rows from `tbl_2` that exist en `tbl_1` in the two columns (I assume a and b) with a inner `merge`:

```
print (pd.concat([tbl_1, 
                  tbl_1[['a','b']].merge(tbl_2, how='inner')]))
   a  b  c
0  1  2  x
1  3  4  y
2  5  6  z
0  3  4  b
1  5  6  c
```